# Trouble installing Osmosis for OpenStreetMap on Mac OS Monterey

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I want to install [Osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Example_usage) on my Macbook, which currently is running MacOS Monterey 12.0.1

Following the installation instructions, I did the following:

1. I [downloaded](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Downloading) the latest version (0.48.3 at the time of this posting)
2. I navigated to the [OSX installation instructions](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Installation#OS_X), and the screenshot below shows the extent of the instructions:

[image]

1. Doing my best to follow (I'm novice with linux command line), I executed the commands in the screenshot above.
2. After moving accordingly, I tried running `osmosis` into the command line to see if anything would come up, but was told the command was not found.
3. When I run the osmosis file (by typing `open bin` when in my user home directory, a new terminal window pops up showing a bunch of documentation about osmosis, and **no way to edit or run any commands**.

```
Last login: Sat Dec  4 18:47:24 on ttys000
/opt/osmosis/bin/osmosis ; exit;
(base) darrenconly@Darrens-MacBook-Pro ~ % /opt/osmosis/bin/osmosis ; exit;
osmosis

Example Usage

Import a planet file into a local PostgreSQL database.

osmosis --read-xml file=~/osm/planbet/planet.osm --write-apidb host="x" database="x" user="x" password="x"

Export a planet file from a local PostgreSQL database.

osmosis --read-apidb host="x" database="x" user="x" password="x" --write-xml file="planet.osm"

Derive a change set between two planet files.

osmosis --read-xml file="planet2.osm" --read-xml file="planet1.osm" --derive-change --write-xml-change file="planetdiff-1-2.osc"

Derive a change set between a planet file and a database.

osmosis --read-mysql host="x" database="x" user="x" password="x" --read-xml file="planet1.osm" --derive-change --write-xml-change file="planetdiff-1-2.osc"

Apply a change set to a planet file.

osmosis --read-xml-change file="planetdiff-1-2.osc" --read-xml file="planet1.osm" --apply-change --write-xml file="planet2.osm"

Sort the contents of a planet file.

osmosis --read-xml file="data.osm" --sort type="TypeThenId" --write-xml file="data-sorted.osm"

The above examples make use of the default pipe connection feature, however a simple read and write planet file command line could be written in two ways. The first example uses default pipe connection, the second explicitly connects the two components using a pipe named "mypipe". The default pipe connection will always work so long as each task is specified in the correct order.

osmosis --read-xml file="planetin.osm" --write-xml file="planetout.osm"

osmosis --read-xml file="planetin.osm" outPipe.0="mypipe" --write-xml file="planetout.osm" inPipe.0="mypipe"

Full usage details are available at: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage


Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

**So all that said, how do I get osmosis to work as described in [these usage examples](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Example_usage)**? When I run `open bin` it appears that the osmosis executable runs, but it doesn't let me do anything or run any commands.

FYI, looks like this question was [asked before on StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386494/seeking-detailed-instructions-on-how-to-install-osmosis-on-macos-10-12) earlier this year, but was less detailed and no one has answered it thus far.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

Short answer: I needed to add the folder path of the osmosis executable to the `$PATH`.

Specific steps I did:

1. Open .zshrc (I'm using zsh, not bash terminal)
2. Add the following to the .zshrc file:

```
# Adding Osmosis executable to path
path+=('/folder/where/osmosis/executable/is')
export PATH
```

After doing the above, you can run osmosis from the command line just like in the [documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Example_usage)

It seems like the OSM wiki's instructions (see screenshot in my original post) are essentially doing the same thing (i.e., simply add the path to the osmosis executable to the `$PATH`), but they didn't work for me. Not sure why.